# Blender 2.81 OpenGL 3.3 Error

Tags: opengl

So recently I got a new computer since my old one was pretty bad and I needed an upgrade. This PC is incredibly fast and powerful but for some reason it's having trouble running Blender 2.81. I've seen other cases similar to mine but there is something unique to mine. So after I installed Blender, I launched it and the window goes white immediately. But then my MONITOR SHUTS OFF. I have no idea why and I haven't read anywhere that anyone else has encountered this, but yeah. My monitor looses signal for a few seconds and in most cases it'll come back on. When it comes back on Blender's window is still white until it eventually gives me the "Blender stopped responding" error and I have to end the process. I read another thread, trying everything that the person listed to try with none of them working until I got to the bottom when they said to place a dll file in Blender's directory. (This is the thread https://developer.blender.org/T55576 I tried all the possible solutions posted by Philipp Oeser). After putting the dll in Blender's directory, I got a new error. It now says, "A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required". I was really puzzled by this because my PC is really new (it was released in November 2019 I believe) and has new components. Here are my PC specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
- OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit

Also this is my first post here so sorry if I did something wrong.

UPDATE: I tried installing Blender 2.79 to see if it would work and it ran without a problem. I'll use it for now but I would like to know if there's a solution to this problem because I really want to be able to use Blender 2.8. Thanks for reading this long post.

Comment: `opengl32.dll` is v3.2, hence the error  Have you installed the latest driver for your card?.

Comment: I did check and all of them are up to date.